# How to use adapter to prevent Faraday from changing capitalize headers

Tags: ruby, adapter, faraday

I'm using Faraday to create an SDK that will interact with an API, and I need to send two headers API_SIGNATURE and API_REQUEST_TIME, so that's what I've created:

```
class APIClient
  def initialize(api_key)
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def get_users
    request.post('/users')
  end

  private

  def request
    Faraday.new(@@BASE_API_URL, headers: headers)
  end

  def headers
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    return {
      'API_SIGNATURE': Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@api_key + timestamp),
      'API_REQUEST_TIME': timestamp
    }
  end
end
```

And for some reason Faraday is changing `API_SIGNATURE` to `Api-Signature` and `API_REQUEST_TIME` to `Api-Request-Time`.

I would like to prevent that from happening. Someone suggested to use patron:

```
  def request
    Faraday.new(@@BASE_API_URL, headers: headers) do |faraday|
      faraday.adapter :patron
    end
  end
```

But that doesn't work. The following error is raised:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session.rb:330:in `handle_request': Operation timed out after 1004 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (Faraday::TimeoutError)
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session.rb:330:in `request'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/faraday-0.17.0/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:29:in `call'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/faraday-0.17.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:143:in `build_response'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/faraday-0.17.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:387:in `run_request'
        from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/faraday-0.17.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:175:in `post'
        from api.rb:32:in `analyze_text'
        from api.rb:38:in `full_analysis'
        from api.rb:65:in `<main>'
```

Thank you.

======= Update ==========

The problem reduced:

```
headers = { API_SIGNATURE: '', API_REQUEST_TIME: '' }

conn = Faraday.new('https://api.test.io', headers: headers) do |f|
  f.adapter :patron
end

puts conn.headers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because Faraday uses Net::HTTP by default and [Net::HTTP changes the case of your header keys](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/747). You can read more about this issue at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8864627/3784008).

You can get around this by using one of the other available adapters listed at https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/adapters/:

- https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/adapters/excon
- https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/adapters/patron
- https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/adapters/httpclient

Or external adapters that require another gem:

- https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus
- https://github.com/lostisland/faraday-http

Your specific implementation of Patron looks correct, so try using one of the other adapters to see if you have any better luck.

**Update**

I loaded your updated example and tested it myself. The solution is to use stringified keys. You're using symbolized keys.

```
# symbolized
headers = { API_SIGNATURE: '', API_REQUEST_TIME: '' }
=> {
       :API_SIGNATURE => "",
    :API_REQUEST_TIME => ""
}
```

This returns:

```
puts conn.headers
{"Api-Signature"=>"", "Api-Request-Time"=>"", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.17.0"}
```

vs:

```
# stringified
headers = { 'API_SIGNATURE' => '', 'API_REQUEST_TIME' => '' }
=> {
       "API_SIGNATURE" => "",
    "API_REQUEST_TIME" => ""
}
```

Now you get the proper values:

```
puts conn.headers
{"API_SIGNATURE"=>"", "API_REQUEST_TIME"=>"", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.17.0"}
```

At a glance, your original example *appears* stringified but is not (which is why I didn't catch it):

```
{
  'API_SIGNATURE': '',
  'API_REQUEST_TIME': ''
}
=> {
       :API_SIGNATURE => "",
    :API_REQUEST_TIME => ""
}
```

Using a colon for your hash key in Ruby automatically makes it a symbol, even if it's a quoted string. You need to use the hash rocket syntax for stringified keys.

Comment: That's so weird, none of them are working. Do you think it could be the Ruby version I'm using? (2.5.3 installed with rvm).

Comment: Reduce your example so you're not using a class, just a simple `Faraday.new(...) do |f|` block with all your data hard-coded into it, and try again.

Comment: It's pretty simple in Ruby. Do you want a symbolized string for the key? Use a colon. (`{ foo: 'bar' }`) Do you want to use any object at all for the key and not have it changed? Use a hash rocket. (`{ 1 => 'bar' }` or `{ [] => 'bar' }` or `{ Faraday.new => 'bar' }` or `{ 'foo' => 'bar' }` or even `{ :foo => 'bar' }`)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use rocket assignation instead of colons. Like this:

```
headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': '0000'
    }
...
conn.headers
=> {"Content-type"=>"application/json", "X-api-key"=>"0000", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.17.3"}
```

VS

```
headers = {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'x-api-key' => '0000'
    }
conn.headers
=> {"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "x-api-key"=>"0000", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.17.3"}
```

Note how the x was capitalized with colons vs how it was NOT using rockets.