# How to add uppercase to http request headers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

do you know why Rails always convert all header keys to downcase?

the example I have a request like this :

```
uri = URI.parse("https://yoururl.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.add_feild("Code", "asdasdd212312312SDw")
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Accept"] = "text/plain"
request['RequestSignature'] = "/DlWKm99HgYLXKJTdiSBO"
```

but when I check **request.each_header.entries**, I got results like this :

```
[["accept-encoding", "gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3"], ["accept", "text/plain"], ["user-agent", "Ruby"], ["host", "your-api"], ["content-type", "application/json"], ["requestsignature", "123"]]
```

seems like all the headers converted to downcase. do you know how to make the header still consistent with the input?

Comment: HTTP header names are case-insensitive

Comment: hi @Stefan thanks for your answer, but do you know how to make the request use case sensitive? because now my request always failed because third party server only accept RequestSignature but my request always sent requestsignature -_-

Comment: Maybe [How do I preserve case with http.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8864627/477037) helps

Comment: BTW, `URI` and `Net::HTTP` are from Ruby's standard library. (not Rails)

Comment: @Stefan thanks you help me a lot. it's working ...

let me answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @stefan (see comment above). So the solution is to add this new class and save it on lib or app/services:

```
class ImmutableHeaderKey
  attr_reader :key

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def downcase
    self
  end

  def capitalize
    self
  end

  def capitalize!
    self
  end

  def split(*)
    [self]
  end

  def hash
    key.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    key.eql? other.key.eql?
  end

  def to_s
    def self.to_s
      key
    end
    self
  end
end
```

What you need to do for your request is similar. Tested on Net::HTTP and I think this will work for HTTPParty also:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://yoursite.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
header_signature = ImmutableHeaderKey.new('RequestSignature')
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Accept"] = "text/plain"
request[header_signature] = "/DlWKm99HgYLXKJTdiSBO"
```

Note: Tested on Faraday and this method didn't work.