# Post Request from client With Proper Headers Always return 401- UnAuthorized

Tags: ruby, curl, sinatra, rest-client, net-http

Am a newbie to ruby. I am trying to invoke a REST API from ruby code. I have tried the code with both as standalone ruby code and inside a application using sinatra. But am facing same issue every where. Below are the options I have tried.

My Code to Invoke Post API using RestClient. Have modified the data to make it generic

```
    url="https://myapiurl.com/endpointname"
    person={"name"=>"Sample Name","age"=>"20"}
    headers={
        "Content-Type"=>"application/json",
        "api-key"=>"ABCDEFGHIJKL"
    }

    response=RestClient.post url,person.to_json,headers
    puts response
```

I wrote the above block of code in a function and tried calling. But I  got response as below

```
{"status": 401, "error":"Unauthorized Access"}
```

I tried the same api via postman with below settings and was able to get a proper response from the api.

```
URL : https://myapiurl.com/endpointname
Headers : Content-Type: application/json, api-key:"ABCDEFGHIJKL"
Body: Raw:application/json: {"name":"Sample Name","age":"20"}
```

When I tried not passing `api-key` in the headers via postman I got similar response as I got via ruby code.

Next I tried generating code from postman option. Below is the code that got generated from postman for Ruby(Net::Http).
I removed the post params of `cache-control` and `postman-token` from the ruby code and tried running the ruby code. Again I got the same 'Unauthorized' response only !

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://myapiurl.com/endpointname")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
request["api-key"] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
request["postman-token"] = 'some value got generated'
request.body = "{\"name\":\"Sample Name\",\"age\":\"20\"}"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

I suspected is it some IP level issue is blocking hence tried used curl command to hit the api as below. I got proper response from the API.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://myapiurl.com/endpointname \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'api-key: ABCDEGHIJKL' \
  -d '{"name":"Sample Name","age":"20"}'
```

I believe that the `api-key` is not getting passed to the request via the ruby code. Is my way of sending the `api-key` in headers via ruby code correct?

Comment: This is weird. Try changing your url to `http://localhost/` and capture the TCP packet using some tool like tcpdump or fiddler, and see if the header `api-key` is there. Don't worry about the failure of the request. Just make sure it's plain `http`, not `https`.

Comment: I checked it's going as http. I tried by sending my request to [requestbin](https://requestb.in/). The header am sending is "x-api-key". But it's being sent as "X-Api-Key".  I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710373/preserving-case-in-http-headers-with-rubys-nethttp . Do we have some other way which we can achieve this?