# How to preserve custom headers case in ruby 2.6.5

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am able to access api when try wit curl cmd, but same not able to access with net/http,

I did the string patch as per this link [Preserving case in HTTP headers with Ruby's Net:HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710373/preserving-case-in-http-headers-with-rubys-nethttp) and it was working well with ruby 2.2.4,

but recently we migrated to ruby 2.6.5 version, since then we are facing this issue again.

can anyone could help me with it.

sample code

```
token = JSON.parse(token_id)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  sso_token = token["headers"][0]["value"][0]
  request[CaseSensitiveString.new('sso_token')] = sso_token
  request["Accept"] = "application/json"
  req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https"
  }
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
  response.code
  response.body

class CaseSensitiveString < String
def downcase
  self
end
def capitalize
  self
end
```

end

Comment: Can you add some of your code for us to get a better idea of your setup?

Comment: Hi @bwalshy 
I have added the sample code, could you please check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Ruby to respect underscore in Net::HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838996/how-to-force-ruby-to-respect-underscore-in-nethttp-header)

Comment: @anothermh - it requires curl lib.dll for http requests, could you please provide with net/http which would help for us

Comment: As the accepted answer at the linked question points out, there is no reliable, long-term solution for Net::HTTP to allow this. The correct answer is to use something that does not require extra steps, ugly hacks, or monkey patching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I needed to patch net/http as we have large existing project and its working with below code for ruby 2.5 and above

```
module Net::HTTPHeader 
    def capitalize(name)
     name 
    end 
    private :capitalize 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue now with ruby 3.0.6. Looking through the Net::HTTP::Header code, I found out that a `split` is being done on the header (https://github.com/wycats/net-http/blob/master/lib/net2/http/header.rb#LL177C13-L177C13). Therefore, `CaseSensitiveString` should now implement a `split` method, yielding an array of `CaseSensitiveString`:

```rb
class CaseSensitiveString < String
  def downcase
    self
  end

  def capitalize
    self
  end

  def split(arg)
    super(arg).map { |str| CaseSensitiveString.new(str) }
  end

  def to_s
    self
  end
end
```